# Struggling with a simple IF function results

Tags: microsoft-excel

=IF(R11>1,AVERAGE(R10:R11)," ")

R11 is a blank cell and R10 is a value of 46.87 ...

The IF function calculation is loaded in cell P49 of a separate table, I am looking for an average of the 2 cells, I expect the results to be empty... however, the results is 46.87 ??

I expect my results to be blank (empty) if there is no value in R11... but if there is value in R10, it loads the R10 in the cell P49...

Comment: How is R11 filled?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your problem. I have R10 with 46.87 and R11 is blank. When using your formula, I correctly get an empty cell. Are you sure R11 is blank?

Comment: Actually R11 has a calculation in it as well. 
 =IF((P10+Q10)>1,(P10+Q10),"")

Comment: The calculation result is blank...

Comment: That is the problem `""` is greater than `1`. try: `=IF(trim(R11)<>"",AVERAGE(R10:R11),"")` or `=IF(ISNUMBER(R11),AVERAGE(R10:R11),"")`

Comment: Those both work ... I had used the TRIM command but did not use <>... I kept the >1 but failed to get the results

Comment: - can you help me understand this fix... is it because the calculation made the cell have a value and actually wasn't blank?   Also, what is the difference in the 2 formulas you suggested? is there a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a different approach.

Since you are dealing with numbers, numerical values that is, and no interest is apparent in R11 having any other kind of data, I would suggest no funny business, just do one of two things, both of which force a value of zero in the cases in which R11 currently results in the value "".

1. Use an actual "0" in the formula in R11 instead of the current "". This DOES have drawbacks... you might not want 0's there, since it would be returning an actual zero it could, in general, be a problem in figuring an average as it would now often be one more data point and one might not wish that (i.e.:  one might not wish the above average to be 23.435 if R11 results in a 0) though in your use, that would not arise, and there might be other cells that rely upon it to be "", not "0".
2. Better would be to convert it to a zero IN your formula:  for the comparison portion, which would have the advantage of leaving the cell the data originates in as "" while still ensuring it is truly evaluated as a "0" in the `R11>1` test. Since it is not an actual zero, it cannot ever affect the taking of an average any differently than it does now (because it is being ignored now while it sometimes would not be if it were a real 0).

To do the latter approach, modify your formula to this:

```
=IF(  N(R11)  >1,AVERAGE(R10:R11)," ")
```

If you do the above, the test will perform exactly as you wish and since the test fails, the `FALSE` result will happen:  the `" "`  and you would have what you want.

There are a lot of ways to force a `FALSE` that would seem to have nothing to do with the "real content" of R11 and they can be very useful (so long as they work based upon the content in question rather than just being arbitrary, and the offered ideas do so...) when there is nothing better. But the above IS better because it acts in a DIRECT WAY to perform a test that is in every way exactly the test you wished to perform before Excel's screwiness got in the way. Of the two approaches, `TRIM()` and `ISNUMBER()`, the latter would be better since it is closer to directly testing a trait you are interested in, **so to answer your question in the comments**, I'd go that route here and only use `TRIM()` if alphanumeric values were part of what you were doing (which is clearly not the case here!).

IF I did not have `N()` available!